# In SharePoint online how we can enable Configure audit settings for a site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, auditing, logs

In SharePoint 2010, 2013 & 2016 on-premises we use to work with Audit setting using the approach mentioned in this link @ [configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-f5a346d0-ee0f-4412-a5e6-d9b5abaa1012](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-f5a346d0-ee0f-4412-a5e6-d9b5abaa1012).

But inside our SharePoint online modern communication site i can not find this setting , so my question is if inside SharePoint online we still have the ability to Configure audit settings for a site collection as we used to do in SharePoint on-premises?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online no longer support choosing specific events to edit. Audit Log Reports will still be available as usual but powered by the Unified Audit Pipeline. Please refer to **[this document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/configure-audit-data-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2#ID0EAADAAA=Modern)** for complete list of audited events. Please note that we do not support list items as of now.

[image]

**Reference：**

- **[In SharePoint online how we can enable Configure audit settings for
  a site collection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/453367/in-sharepoint-online-how-we-can-enable-configure-a.html)**

======================= **Updated Answer** =======================

You can click on **Export results** >> **Download all results** to get .cvs file. Then you can share this .cvs file with the group of people.

[image]

Comment: so what we can do if we want to generate a report for all the actions that has been done for a list or a library and send the report to a group of people?

Comment: Hi, John John. I have updated answer under initial My Answer. Hope this can help you to solve issue. Have a nice day!